# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax [Php PDO]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have searched for an answer on numerous sites, however it seems like no one have had the same problem as I am having right now, the ones I have come across.

The issue is that am getting this error message:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '), NULL)' at line 2

The beginning of my code looks like this. I have been staring at it but I don't seem to find the problem, any help?

```
<?php
$dbhost="host";   <-- this is line 2.
$dbname="db";
$dbusername="user";
$dbpassword="pass";

ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST["namn"])) {

try {
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `eventcustomers` (`namn`,`enamn`,`datum`,`personnr`,`kon`,`telefon`,`epost`,`allergier`,`kategori`,`brodtext`,`reseto`,`eid`)
    VALUES(:namn, :enamn, NOW(), :personnr, :kon, :telefon, :epost, :allergier, :kategori, :brodtext, time(), :eid)");

$stmt->bindParam(':namn', $_POST["namn"]);
$stmt->bindParam(':enamn', $_POST["enamn"]);
$stmt->bindParam(':personnr', $_POST["personnr"]);
$stmt->bindParam(':kon', $_POST["kon"]);
$stmt->bindParam(':telefon', $_POST["telefon"]);
$stmt->bindParam(':epost', $_POST["epost"]);
$stmt->bindParam(':allergier', $_POST["allergier"]);
$stmt->bindParam(':kategori', $_POST["kategori"]);
$stmt->bindParam(':brodtext', $_POST["brodtext"]);
$stmt->bindParam(':eid', $_POST["eid"]);
$stmt->execute();
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
$link = null;

    ?>
```

I have tried without the usage of (`), but the messsage is the same.

Comment: Maybe a error is in database table ?

Comment: Hi, I tried to implement the changes but nothing worked.. so its still open :D

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing worked"? Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Yes thats correct.

Comment: Show us the part of the code where you bind the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This error basically is telling you there's an error in your SQL syntax - the surrounding PHP isn't going to help you, so long as you're troubleshooting the correct query.

(reformatted for easier viewing)

```
INSERT INTO
    `eventcustomers`
    (`namn`,
    `enamn`,
    `datum`,
    `personnr`,
    `kon`,
    `telefon`,
    `epost`,
    `allergier`,
    `kategori`,
    `brodtext`,
    `reseto`,
    `eid`)
VALUES
    (:namn,
    :enamn,
    NOW(),
    :personnr,
    :kon,
    :telefon,
    :epost,
    :allergier,
    :kategori,
    :brodtext,
    time(), /* this is your problem */
    :eid)
```

Here's your clue: `the right syntax to use near '), NULL)'`: You know you've got a close parentheses, comma, value, close parentheses.

That points to your use of the [`time()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time).  You're using it like `NOW()` but that's not how it's intended to be used.  You need an argument in there.

I believe you just want to use `NOW()` instead, if it's a time-only field it'll automatically use only the time portion of the timestamp.

```
VALUES
    (:namn,
    :enamn,
    NOW(),
    :personnr,
    :kon,
    :telefon,
    :epost,
    :allergier,
    :kategori,
    :brodtext,
    NOW(), /* fixed! */
    :eid)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that didn't fix it.. :(

Comment: I'm guessing you have a similar error lower in your code in another query.  See if you get the same error after commenting out this first query.  If so, it's a different query.

Comment: Jason, good point. I am using Swedish letters in my insertion query and I am facing the same issue. If you have a solution for that please update us.